# Namenode not getting started on Hortonworks Sandbox

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run HDFS but the namenode is not getting started, I have alse tried to start it through command like

```
sudo -l /usr/hdp/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /usr/hdp/hadoop/conf start namenode
```

but it doesn't got started. I have seen the hadoop logs and got the following errors:

**Errors**

```
2015-04-28 10:36:04,752 FATAL namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1509)) - Failed to start namenode.java.io.FileNotFoundException: /hadoop/hdfs/namenode/in_use.lock (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.tryLock(Storage.java:706)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.lock(Storage.java:678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1022)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:741)at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1504) 2015-04-28 10:36:04,755 INFO  util.ExitUtil (ExitUtil.java:terminate(124)) - Exiting with status 1 2015-04-28 10:36:04,834 INFO  namenode.NameNode (StringUtils.java:run(659)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG: /************************************************************
```

Comment: Posted log is not sufficient. Post complete log.

Comment: hii Rajesh , I had uploaded the full exception

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to start namenode.java.io.FileNotFoundException: **/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/in_use.lock (Permission denied)**
>       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)

This error might arise if you do not start namenode as hadoop user. Actually, you are trying to run it as root user but the file `/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/in_use.lock` is owned by hadoop user.

Do not use sudo to start hadoop processess. Try to start it without sudo. Try this:

```
/usr/hdp/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /usr/hdp/hadoop/conf start namenode
```